# Flutter- how to create and download pdf in background?

Tags: flutter, pdf, google-cloud-firestore, syncfusion, flutter-local-notification

I have created an ecommerce app.

in my app there are over 5000 products and in my cart there are over 300 plus products.

in my cart there is an download button which will download the data(images, id, name, quantity) into a pdf.

I have used https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf this plugin to create pdf.

the problem is when there are 10 to 20 products in cart it is getting downloaded quickly but when there are over 300 products it getting downloaded very slowly.

the logic I have added in my code is first it will get all the data from firebase cloud fire store where my data is stored and will store it in a list after that when download button is clicked I am adding that list in my pdf using for loop.

I want when download button is clicked it should run that loop in the background and create the pdf and while it was being created I want to show a progress notification the one where google drive shows it progress notification. after it is completed when clicked on that notification it should open the downloaded pdf.

I searched on google but did not got any solution.

it would be of great help if I got solution for this problem.

Please help guys! Thanks In Advance!!.

this is the pdf code when download button is clicked.

```
Future<void> generateInvoice() async {
    //Create a PDF document.
    final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
    //Add page to the PDF
    final PdfPage page = document.pages.add();
    //Get page client size
    final Size pageSize = page.getClientSize();
    //Create a PdfGrid

    Future<List<int>> _readImageData(String name) async {
      final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/$name');
      return data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    }
    page.graphics.drawImage(
        PdfBitmap(await _readImageData('images/unnamed.png')),
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, pageSize.width, 100)
    );
    //Generate PDF grid.
    PdfGrid grid = PdfGrid();
    //Secify the columns count to the grid.
    grid.columns.add(count: 4);
    //Create the header row of the grid.
    final PdfGridRow headerRow = grid.headers.add(1)[0];
    //Set style
    headerRow.style.backgroundBrush = PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(22, 111, 105));
    headerRow.style.textBrush = PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(187, 167, 85));
    headerRow.cells[0].value = 'SR NO';
    headerRow.cells[0].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.center;
    headerRow.cells[1].value = 'PRODUCT IMAGE';
    headerRow.cells[1].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.center;
    headerRow.cells[2].value = 'PRODUCT DETAILS';
    headerRow.cells[2].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.center;
    headerRow.cells[3].value = 'QUANTITY';
    headerRow.cells[3].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.center;
    //Add rows
    int sr_no = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < _totalItems; i++) {
      final PdfGridRow row = grid.rows.add();
      var imageResponse1 = await get(Uri.parse(photoArray[i]));
      sr.add(sr_no);
      print(sr[i]);
      sr_no = sr_no + 1;
      print(sr_no);
      row.cells[0].value = sr[i].toString();
      row.cells[0].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.center;
      row.cells[0].stringFormat.lineAlignment = PdfVerticalAlignment.middle;
      row.cells[1].value = PdfBitmap(imageResponse1.bodyBytes.toList());
      //row.cells[1].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.center;
      row.cells[1].stringFormat.lineAlignment = PdfVerticalAlignment.middle;
      row.cells[2].value =
      '   DESIGN NO - ${skuArray[i]}\n   G. WT - ${metalArray[i]}\n   D. WT - ${stoneArray[i]}\n   COLOUR - ${goldColorArray[i]}';
      row.cells[2].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.left;
      row.cells[2].stringFormat.lineAlignment = PdfVerticalAlignment.middle;
      row.cells[3].value = dropdown[i].toString();
      row.cells[3].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.center;
      row.cells[3].stringFormat.lineAlignment = PdfVerticalAlignment.middle;
      grid.rows[i].height = 160;
    }
    grid.columns[0].width = 70;
    grid.columns[3].width = 70;

    for (int i = 0; i < headerRow.cells.count; i++) {
      headerRow.cells[i].style.cellPadding =
          PdfPaddings(bottom: 5, left: 5, right: 5, top: 5);
    }
    final PdfStringFormat format = PdfStringFormat(
        alignment: PdfTextAlignment.center,
        lineAlignment: PdfVerticalAlignment.middle);
    //Add a new row
    final PdfGridRow totalRow = grid.rows.add();
    totalRow.cells[0].value = 'TOTAL QUANTITY';
    //Set column span
    totalRow.cells[0].columnSpan = 3;
    totalRow.cells[0].style.stringFormat = format;
    totalRow.height = 25;

    int sum = dropdown.fold(0, (p, c) => p + c);

    totalRow.cells[3].value = sum.toString();
    totalRow.cells[3].stringFormat.alignment = PdfTextAlignment.center;
    totalRow.cells[3].stringFormat.lineAlignment = PdfVerticalAlignment.middle;



    grid.draw(
        page: page, bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 120, 0, 0));
    //Save the PDF document
    final List<int> bytes = document.save();
    //Dispose the document.
    document.dispose();
    //Get external storage directory
    Directory directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
    //Get directory path
    String path = directory.path;
    print(path);
    //Create an empty file to write PDF data
    File file = File('$path/CART-CATALOGUE.pdf');
    //Write PDF data
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    setState(() {
      isApiCallProcess = false;
    });
    //Open the PDF document in mobile
    OpenFile.open('$path/CART-CATALOGUE.pdf');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Syncfusion Flutter PDF](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf) package is written natively in Dart for supporting all the platforms and its only works on the main thread (synchronously) and we do not have asynchronous support. Due to this, the UI has been stopped animating for doing the very large process. So we request you to use the [Isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) to overcome the issue. We have created a simple sample for your reference as follows.

Sample link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/PdfSample47074776

Comment: this contains static method which is affecting the array that i want to add in the row and my whole data is dynamic